# Loki/Linux Personal Realtime IDS and/or IPS

Tags: linux, ids

In the old days i used to use firewall apps on windows that would have intrusion detection that would alert me while on my system and/or email. For instance, i would see a popup that says:  "Warning: port scan detected from remote ip x.x.x.x"

Does something similiar exist for loki/ubuntu?

I was looking at snort, but that seems way over complicated, etc.  I just want personal protection and warnings (or preventions) of real time attacks.

thanks :-)